# Using Ruby On Rails to write a GUI for C project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, c, user-interface

I have large programs written in C that provide an interface for various hardware chips and devices (over SPI mainly). I want to create GUI for these C programs using Ruby On Rails on browser. Meaning, whenever I connect my hardware, press an exe file (on windows) and then redirect to a ROR web app that would control the chip parameters (the same thing that's done by CVI lab in .uir file only way nicer).

I've seen a few ways to integrate Ruby code in C programs and vice versa. Is there a simple way to use ROR apps and create hooks to C variables? is there a simpler way to write ROR code in a C program as is (I've seen Swig and Ruby on C API)?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not simply use a wrapper around the `` syntax for ruby, and execute the programs from there? You should be able to create the hooks in ruby.

Comment: The common way is to have C simple command programs that take their parameters from the command line, and then to have GUI tools that build the command parameters and simply execute an external command. But your current question is rather broad...

Comment: @SergeBallesta is what you're talking about suppose to work on a web framework (ruby on rails)? my question is not very broad. I have a C program that currently uses a simple looking GUI from CVI lab windows. I want to build a nicer looking GUI using Ruby On Rails and asking for the best way to do so. shahe Ansar Thanks, I'll look in to it.